# Python GUI building in eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, user-interface, pygtk

I'm wondering is there a tool similar to http://www.eclipse.org/vep/ for Python available? I'd like to be able to use a tool like Visual Editor when building pygtk GUI's. I'm looking for tools to make the task of GUI building less tedious and more fun basically.

Answer (score 1):

[Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) is the best one I used. It's a standalone program, not an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). Not for Eclipse or GTK, but very simple and easy to use with wxPython.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python development plugin for Eclipse, from http://pydev.org. After you install that in Eclipse, you get a PyDev perspective.